# Error haciendo delete C++

Tags: c++

Tengo algo muy simple en C++ (tratando de recordarlo) una librería a la que llamo elemento.h:

```
using namespace std;

typedef struct elemento{
       int clave;
       string nombre;
       string apellido;
       struct elemento *prox;
}Elemento;


Elemento crearElemento(int clave, string nombre, string apellido){
    Elemento e;
    e.clave    = clave;
    e.nombre   = nombre;
    e.apellido = apellido;
    e.prox = NULL;
    return e;
}

void imprimirElemento(Elemento e){
    cout << "-----------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "CLAVE    =" << e.clave << endl;
    cout << "NOMBRE   =" << e.nombre << endl;
    cout << "APELLIDO =" << e.apellido << endl; 
    cout << "-----------------------------------------------" << endl;
}
```

Y tengo otra libreria PilaElemento.h:

```
using namespace std;

typedef Elemento *Pila;

Pila crearPila(){
    Pila aux = NULL;
    return aux;
}

void apilar(Pila &pila, Elemento e) {
        Pila q = new(struct elemento);
        e.prox = pila;
        q = &e;
        pila = q;
}

void desapilar(Pila &pila) {
        Pila aux;   
        aux = pila;
        pila = pila->prox;
        delete aux;
}
Elemento tope(Pila &pila){
    return (elemento)*pila;
}

bool esVacia(Pila &pila) {
    bool log = false;
    if (pila==NULL) log= true;
    return log;
}
```

Todo funciona bien, menos Desapilar, me muestra el siguiente mensaje de error:

> pila(5291,0x7fff765f5000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fff5f143220:
>   pointer being freed was not allocated
>       *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
>       Abort trap: 6

Básicamente lo quise dejar así para no tocar la Libreria de Pila, sino solamente la de elemento (y no quiero usar POO)

Comment: No me parece ver el código en que ese error salta. ¿Podrías incluir tu función `main`? (por favor).

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct elemento{
       int clave;
       string nombre;
       string apellido;
       struct elemento *prox;
}Elemento;
```

Como ya he dicho otras veces: C++ **no es** C. Las estructuras no necesitan tirar de `typedef` para generar código legible. Esto que has puesto es equivalente a:

```
struct Elemento{
       int clave;
       string nombre;
       string apellido;
       Elemento *prox;
};
```

En cuanto a este alias:

```
typedef Elemento *Pila;
```

No solo no sería necesario sino que llega a complicar la lectura del código, puesto que tienes que acordarte de que `Pila` es un puntero (al menos el nombre podía haber reflejado tal característica: `PilaPtr` o `ElementoPtr`... yo personalmente en este tipo de ejercicios no usaría el alias.

Seguimos convirtiendo pseudo C en C++:

```
// Vale, funciona, pero ¿en serio?
Pila q = new(struct elemento);

// Lo que podría esperar encontrarse la gente
// Se ve raro que crees un objeto de un tipo y lo almacenes en un tipo distinto
Pila q = new Elemento;

// Lo que espera encontrarse la gente
Elemento* elemento = new Elemento;
```

Y empezamos a sacar a la luz los problemas:

```
void apilar(Pila &pila, Elemento e) {
        Pila q = new Elemento; // <<--- 1
        e.prox = pila;
        q = &e; // <<--- 2
        pila = q;
}
```

Veamos:

1. Creas un objeto con new... y dos líneas más abajo haces que el puntero apunte a otra posición de memoria... perdiendo la memoria reservada con `new`
2. `e` es un objeto que has pasado **por valor**. El objeto `e` muere, literalmente, cuando el código abandona la función, por lo que la referencia `&e` pasa a apuntar a basura.

La función debería lucir más bien así:

```
void apilar(Pila &pila, Elemento e) {
        Pila q = new Elemento(e);
        q->prox = pila;
        pila = q;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por responder PaperBirdMaster

Aquí coloco el Main.

```
#include "elemento.h"
#include "Pila-elemento.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    Pila pila = crearPila();

    Elemento e;

    e = crearElemento(10, "Ana", "Marquez");
    apilar(pila, e);

    e = crearElemento(30, "Luis", "Gonzalez");
    apilar(pila, e);
    apilar(pila, crearElemento(14, "Rosa", "Perez"));
    //imprimirElemento(tope(pila));
    cout << "-----------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "--------------------DESAPILANDO----------------" << endl;
    while(!esVacia(pila)){
        imprimirElemento(tope(pila));
        desapilar(pila);                
        cout << "-----------------------------------------------" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Esto debería ir en la pregunta. Edítala para añadir este contenido y después, por favor, borra esta respuesta ya que no es tal cosa